# error: ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in assignment

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, nachos

I get this error message, and I don't seem to understand it. 
What does it mean by ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in assignment? . And the Fork function only takes the function name and a number

Thread::Fork(VoidFunctionPtr func, int arg)

Error message:

```
../threads/threadtest.cc: In function `void ServerThread(int)':
../threads/threadtest.cc:72: ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in assignment
../threads/threadtest.cc:78: implicit declaration of function `int WorkerThread(...)'
```

REGION:

72 - 78:

```
  nextReq = list -> Remove();


  //check till the end                                                                     
  while (nextReq != NULL)
    {
      WorkerThread(&nextReq);
```

code:

```
#include "copyright.h"
#include "system.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "request.h"

extern void serve(char *url);
//GLOBAL VARIABLE LIST
List *list;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ThreadTest
//  read file and serve urls
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void 
ClientThread(int request)
{
  const int sz = 50;
  char url[sz];

  FILE *fp = fopen("url.txt", "r");
  if (!fp)
    printf("  Cannot open file url.txt!\n");
  else {
    int pos = 0;
    char c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF || pos == sz - 1) {
      if (c == '\n') {
    url[pos] = '\0';
    serve(url);
    pos = 0;

    //Store necessary information in a Request object for each request. 
    Request req(url, request, 1);

    Request *reqq = &req; //req points to the object
    list->Append(reqq);
      }
      else {
    url[pos++] = c;
      }
      c = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void
ServerThread(int which)
{

  Request *nextReq;
  //gets the first node off the list
  nextReq = list -> Remove();


  //check till the end
  while (nextReq != NULL)
    {
      WorkerThread(nextReq);

    }


}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void
WorkerThread (Request req)
{
  serve(req.url);
  currentThread -> Yield();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void
ThreadTest()
{
    DEBUG('t', "Entering SimpleTest");
    printf("THREAD TEST");

    //Thread *c = new Thread("client thread");
    Thread *s = new Thread("server thread");

    s->Fork(ServerThread, 1);
    ClientThread(0);

}
```

Comment: Surely this was not the best [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you could manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be one of the offending lines:

```
nextReq = list -> Remove();
```

It appears that `list->Remove()` returns a `void *`.  C++ *requires* a cast to turn this into another pointer (C does not).  So change this to:

```
nextReq = static_cast<Request *>(list -> Remove());
```

(Alternatively, consider making `List` a template class so you can avoid these kinds of unsafe casts.  Based on your code, the STL class `std::queue<Request>` should fulfill your needs here.)

The second offending line is your call to `WorkerThread()` before it is defined.  You need to add a prototype for the function prior to your definition of `ServerThread()`.  Otherwise the compiler does not know what its prototype is, and it should complain once it reaches the real definition of `ServerThread()` that it does not match the prototype that it deduced earlier.

```
void WorkerThread(Request);

void
ServerThread(int which)
{
    // ...
```

(Or, since `WorkerThread()` does not call `ServerThread()`, you could just swap the order of the definitions of the two functions to resolve the problem.)

---

Further, note that this code is bad:

```
Request req(url, request, 1);

Request *reqq = &req; //req points to the object
list->Append(reqq);
```

You construct an object and then push a pointer to the stack-allocated object onto a list.  When `ClientThread()` returns, this object will be destroyed and you are left with a pointer to an object that no longer exists.  Using this pointer will trigger undefined behavior.  Consider instead allocating a new `Request` on the heap by using `Request *reqq = new Request(url, request, 1);` (but don't forget to `delete` the object after you process it).

Or, better yet, use `std::queue<Request>` as I suggested earlier -- then you can just `queue.emplace(url, request, 1);`.  But note that you do need a way to synchronize access to the queue from multiple threads.

Comment: In the function 'void ServerThread(int): I get this error:
conversion from `Request **' to non-scalar type `Request' requested.     WorkerThread(&nextReq);

Comment: @monkeydoodle You need to do `WorkerThread(*nextReq);` instead. `WorkerThread()` accepts a `Request`, not any kind of pointer.